# Flutter: Unable to connect to VM service at *link* WebSocketChannelException: WebSocket connection failed

Tags: flutter, dart, http, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a Flutter application that utilizes GoogleMaps APIs. After adding a function to search using the Places API, my application shuts down a few seconds after compiling with the following error:

Error after compiling

[image: 1]

I've updated http, GoogleMaps SDK for ios, the podfile, and Flutter itself. None of those things seem to fix the problem. Below is part of the code I added that seems to be causing this issue:

Potentially problematic code

[image: 2]

I'm unsure what WebSocket is, but I'm utilizing http to get the input from user text in order to generate the location. Any ideas on how to go about fixing this? I couldn't find any solutions just by searching the error.